# Issue with getting batch script to print keeps given a error about set was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, dayofweek

Okay I am trying to get the script to print the day of the week and after the test would like to get the script to go more advanced once i get it working correctly

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET /a count=0
FOR /F "skip=1" %%D IN ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek') DO (
    if "!count!" GTR "0" GOTO next
    set dow=%%D
    IF %dow%==1 set dowday=Monday
    IF %dow%==2 set dowday=Tuesday
    IF %dow%==3 set dowday=Wednesday
    IF %dow%==4 set dowday=Thursday
    IF %dow%==5 set dowday=Friday
    IF %dow%==6 set dowday=Saturday
    IF %dow%==7 set dowday=Sunday
    SET /a count+=1
)
:next
echo %dowday%
pause
```

Comment: In addition to the delayed expansion thing, Sundays will have %dow%==0, not 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You enable delayed expansion, but then fail to use it. You need delayed expansion because you are setting a variable within a loop, and then trying to reference the value of the variable within the same loop. Normal expansion occurs when the statement (or block) is parsed (before the loop is iterated). Delayed expansion gives you the value when the statement is executed during the iteration.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET /a count=0
FOR /F "skip=1" %%D IN ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek') DO (
    if "!count!" GTR "0" GOTO next
    set dow=%%D
    IF !dow!==0 set dowday=Sunday
    IF !dow!==1 set dowday=Monday
    IF !dow!==2 set dowday=Tuesday
    IF !dow!==3 set dowday=Wednesday
    IF !dow!==4 set dowday=Thursday
    IF !dow!==5 set dowday=Friday
    IF !dow!==6 set dowday=Saturday
    SET /a count+=1
)
:next
echo %dowday%
pause
```

In your case, you could avoid delayed expansion by using %%D in the IF statements, and unconditionally GOTO :next at the end of the loop since count will always be greater than 0.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
SET /a count=0
FOR /F "skip=1" %%D IN ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek') DO (
    set dow=%%D
    IF %%D==0 set dowday=Sunday
    IF %%D==1 set dowday=Monday
    IF %%D==2 set dowday=Tuesday
    IF %%D==3 set dowday=Wednesday
    IF %%D==4 set dowday=Thursday
    IF %%D==5 set dowday=Friday
    IF %%D==6 set dowday=Saturday
    SET /a count+=1
    goto next
)
:next
echo %dowday%
pause
```

Comment: thanks this fixed my issue with the log rotation script i was working on for my DAYZ Epoch server to have a daily log backup

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help now the final script is completed

```
@echo off
:: Based off of Server Launch Script by r4z0r49
:: Script Modified and fixed by Sykotix - http://dayz.sykotix.com
:: Day of the week Added By Raziel23x - http://adkgamers.com
::
:: Usage: dayzsrv-log-rotater.bat servername
:: Example 1 - Will update using default profile: dayzsrv-log-rotater.bat 
:: Example 2 - Will update using profile for US6: dayzsrv-log-rotater.bat US6

:::::::::::::: CONFIG ::::::::::::::::::

:: Set your Arma2AO Base installation directory. LEAVE OFF THE ENDING \
set arma2srvpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 2 Operation Arrowhead

:: Set your Default server profile name. This is the name of the directory that stores your server.cfg
:: This will be used in the case that you don't launch this script without the server param.
:: Example: cfgdayz, US6, Chicago13, ect
:: DEFAULTPROFILE
set srvname=instance_11_chernarus

:: Delete Original log files after they have been rotated? This keeps your logs more organized and saves space.
:: This will not work unless the server is stopped first. This option works best set to 1 when using FireDaemon's Pre/Post Service tab
set deloriglogs=1

::::::::::: ADVANCED CONFIG ::::::::::::
:: Don't touch anything below this point unless you know what your doing.

:: Setting Server Profile to Use
IF "%1"=="" (
set servername=%srvname%
) else (
set servername=%1
)

TITLE  DayZ %servername% Server Log Rotater

:: Set Debug Mode
set debug=0
:: Set Debug Timeout in seconds
set dbsecs=10

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::  STOP EDITING ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: Display Debug output
if %debug% == 1 (
echo Server Name = %servername%
echo ArmaII Server Path = "%arma2srvpath%"
timeout %dbsecs%
)

:: Set Time and Date
SET HOUR=%time:~0,2%
SET dtStamp9=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_0%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
SET dtStamp24=%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
::Make Date Stamp
if "%HOUR:~0,1%" == " " (SET dtStamp=%dtStamp9%) else (SET dtStamp=%dtStamp24%)
ECHO Todays Date and time (%date%)(%time%) / %dtStamp%
if %debug% == 1 (
timeout %dbsecs%
)
:: Set Day of the Week --Raziel23x
SETLOCAL
FOR /F "skip=1" %%D IN ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek') DO (

    IF %%D==0 set weekday=Sunday
    IF %%D==1 set weekday=Monday
    IF %%D==2 set weekday=Tuesday
    IF %%D==3 set weekday=Wednesday
    IF %%D==4 set weekday=Thursday
    IF %%D==5 set weekday=Friday
    IF %%D==6 set weekday=Saturday
)

echo (%weekday%) (%date%) (%time%) Starting Log Rotation.

:: Make the Rotated Log Directorys
if exist "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs" goto maketsdir
mkdir "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs"
:maketsdir
if exist "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%" goto makebedir
mkdir "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%"
:makebedir
if exist "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye" goto rotatelogs
mkdir "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye"

:rotatelogs
:: Starting Log Rotation. If there are any other logs, just follow the format below, and make sure to NOT touch any of the varibles.
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\arma2oaserver.RPT" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\arma2oaserver.RPT"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\arma2oaserver.mdmp" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\arma2oaserver.mdmp"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\arma2oaserver.bidmp" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\arma2oaserver.bidmp"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\server_log.txt" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\server_log.txt"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\HiveExt.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\HiveExt.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\scripts.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\scripts.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\createvehicle.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\createvehicle.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\mpeventhandler.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\mpeventhandler.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\publicvariable.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\publicvariable.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\publicvariableval.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\publicvariableval.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\remoteexec.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\remoteexec.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\setdamage.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\setdamage.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\setpos.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\setpos.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\setvariable.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\setvariable.log"
copy "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\addmagazinecargo.log" "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\RotatedLogs\%weekday%\%dtStamp%\BattlEye\addmagazinecargo.log"

echo (%date%) (%time%) Logs are backed up now...
echo (%date%) (%time%) Removing original log files.
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\arma2oaserver.RPT"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\arma2oaserver.mdmp"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\arma2oaserver.bidmp"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\server_console.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\runtime.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\scripts.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\createvehicle.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\mpeventhandler.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\publicvariable.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\publicvariableval.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\remoteexec.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\setdamage.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\setpos.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\setvariable.log"
del /Q /F "%arma2srvpath%\%servername%\BattlEye\addmagazinecargo.log"

if %debug% == 1 (
timeout %dbsecs%
)

:: We're done here.
exit
```

Comment: Using the date and time variables is unreliable as they change from `region to region` and also by `user preferences`.  As you are using `WMIC` then it is better to also use that for the date and time information. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22The+first+four+lines+of+this+code%22+user%3Afoxidrive